# Memory efficient way to store many small objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a simple `Person` class with 4 strings and integer.

```
public class Person
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

We need to store a large number of these in memory. The collection needs to be searchable by any field. Items will be added and deleted as part the life cycle.

The Flyweight pattern doesn't seem work because there isn't a ton of duplicate values at the object, only at the field level. What pattern or strategy would work best to limit memory overhead and perform well?

Comment: How many is "many"?  Do you have a few hundred thousand, a few million, billions, more?  Memory is cheap; most people have lots of it.  If you're talking millions or less, just do whatever is easiest, you probably don't need to worry about reducing the memory footprint.  If you have more, you probably want to put them all in a database and you won't want to ever have them all in memory at once in a C# program.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that most people have lots of memory or the ability to upgrade to lots. A large proportion of our target client PCs only have a couple of gigs at best, easy to blow through that in a 64-bit .NET app doing number crunching. But of course, this is all relative.

Comment: how long is a string?

Comment: I recommend researching object databases, many of which support an 'in-memory' mode.  Basically your requirements (compact size, ability to search, support for large numbers of instances) are all addressed by databases.  Object databases, in particular, automatically deal with metadata so that you don't have to worry about defining tables manually.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth A few million of these items would be several megabytes.  For a PC with several Gigs that's *nothing*.  So even a PC that you consider to "not have a lot of memory" would be able to handle the numbers I'm talking about without problem.  You just proved my point for me.

Comment: @Servy I know, but the memory is cheap and most people have lots of it argument is often a fallacy in the enterprise world where upgrading the memory on all those machines is not necessarily cheap.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I'm not saying you'd need to go and upgrade the machine, I'm saying whatever they already have is probably fine if he's dealing with numbers in that range because nobody would ever *bother* making a machine these days that only has 10 MB of RAM.  It's unthinkable to have so little because RAM is so cheap, even the lowest chips you can buy retail would be able to handle several million of the suckers without problem.

Comment: It would be in the millions, somewhere between 5 and 20 million.

Comment: @user2547359 Then you shouldn't have a problem.  That's not actually going to take *that* much memory.  Just do what seems easiest to you and see if you have a problem.  If you do, post some more specifics (are you getting errors, is it slow, how much memory is actually being used and what are you expecting to get it down to, etc.).  If you don't have problems, then great, you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We need to store a large number of these in memory.

Then an array  `Person[]` would be the leanest way but a `List<Person>` would be close and much easier to work with. Just make sure to minimize re-allocation by using the Capacity parameter.

> The collection needs to be searchable by any field

Easy,  `.Where (p => p.FirstName  == value)`.
Speeding it up with Dictionaries will cost memory.

Comment: Either would probably run out of memory faster than a linked list or other structure, due to the sequential memory allocation of said array and the related fragmentation, would it not?

Comment: The post would indicate he's trying to find ways of using even less memory by, for example, instead of storing an age of 20 in a million items, store 20 once and then have a million items that don't have an age property associated with it, or something along those lines.  In theory, if there is a lot of duplication, something like that may be able to be a net win, but it would be complex.

Comment: @Servy: an `Age` property would be a bad example (too small). You might be able to save a little on some strings (duplicate names are common).

Comment: @HenkHolterman [I think the whole think isn't an issue to begin with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452693/memory-efficient-way-to-store-many-small-objects#comment25356502_17452693), which is why I didn't answer.  If he actually has so much data that these problems are relevant, then I maintain that a database is far and away the best option.  Re-implementing all of the large data management techniques DBs have would be a ton of work for no real return.

Comment: @DavidH - only an issue with (frequent) re-allocation. All other collections would consume more total memory.

Comment: Only partially relevant, but the memory footprint of `Person[]` and `List<Person>` are quite similar, since the list is internally represented as an array. If you're talking about LOTS of these objects, both arrays and lists will suffer (potentially) from Large Object Heap allocation and the inherent fragmentation that comes along with that.

Comment: @DavidH a linked list would consume approximately twice as much total memory, even though it doesn't require it to be sequential.  There are *much* easier ways of dealing with the problem that don't double the memory.  Basically what you want, if you have a single array with that many values, is to create a new class that has a List of arrays, with each inner array being some set batch size (maybe a few hundred thousand) and then have the class's indexer expose it as if the data was sequential.  This gives breaks up the memory into smaller chucks with much, much less overhead than a LL.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of things might work here... First, it's best left as a reference type so that you're not copying structs everywhere when searching. Use `string.Intern(string)` to reduce memory usage on duplicate first and last names as well as postal codes... Finally use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to index these entries by value... Perhaps the `TKey` is string in the case of FirstName and `TValue`' is `List<Person>` so that you can look up the people by said string... This is called an inverted index: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index - an alternative to Dictionary is to implement your own Tree or Trie structure such as a Prefix trie... You trade O(log n) speed for less memory than the O(1) dictionary.

In terms of storing a LOT of them in memory, it depends what a lot is... but ultimately you want to have enough memory to handle them all... Or begin to expand out to distributed systems to share the objects such as a MapReduce pattern, or "paging" onto disk.

Comment: Before using `Intern`, the OP should read the performance considerations from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx . Regarding use of Dictionary, although it is an efficient implementation, it is not super memory efficient, which is what the OP is probably looking for. There is a non-trivial amount of space overhead in Dictionaries.

Comment: @hatchet true, but it would accomplish the goal of O(1) searches for data quite nicely. Can you suggest a more efficient structure?

Comment: The point remains that the OP is looking to reduce memory.  A Dictionary sacrifices memory for speed.  If you have very limited memory you can't do that, you need to sacrifice speed for memory.

Comment: @DavidH - the OP did not ask for O(1), but did ask for memory efficiency.

Comment: I have updated my post to include an O(log n) alternative algorithm to a Dictionary. I was merely **PROPOSING** a way to search, not a definitive implementation.

Comment: @DavidH Even a tree based structure will have a *dramatically* larger memory footprint than something like an array.  It'll be a bit less than a dictionary, but still significant.

Comment: Alright, well then vote my answer which I feel is valid into oblivion then. Whatever makes you happy. :)

Comment: +1 because they're ganging up on you. Their array answer will reduce memory usage, but could be terrible if you don't manage it well as you could crucify the LOH, so neither is it a particularly good answer without some conditions being specified. Also,  managing strings by eliminating duplicates may have more impact than using a dictionary. For example one approach if there is a lot of duplication might be to put the strings in dictionaries and use their hashes to reference them from an index that 's in an array, which might improve both efficiency and memory use. It all depends on the data.

Comment: @JasonWilliams - what do you think is inside Dictionary? Big arrays...two of them. One for the hash buckets, and one for the  entries. The impact on LOH is worse with a Dictionary than it would be with an array of objects. The array of Entry in particular is an array of structs where each element consumes several times more space than a single object reference.

Comment: @JasonWilliams Telling someone to use a Dictionary instead of an array when they're looking to minimize memory is exactly like telling someone to use an array instead of a dictionary if they're looking to optimize search speed.  Using a dictionary costs memory in order to improve lookup speed.  The OP specifically said he wants to reduce memory, so giving an answer that would consume *radically more memory* is a *bad answer*, and thus it's appropriate to downvote it.  Upvoting a *bad answer* just because some people downvoted it harms the site by giving a false impression the answer is valid.

Comment: An answer more suited to the OP's request would be a stable array of objects (where position doesn't change). For each field index, a simple array of int indexes into that array can be used, with binary search for lookups. Not much overhead there. If he used a chunked array (array of arrays) class, that's even better, and it would reduce the cost of inserts/deletes in the index arrays. Dictionary has at a minimum 12 bytes of bookkeeping overhead per element.

Comment: @hatchet, Servy: As I clearly said, neither an array or dictionary is "the answer". I upvoted because this answer makes some good points, and in particular focuses on the important part of the question, which has totally eluded you: size matters, so using a 32-bit int for Age, using 64-bit references for strings, optimising for highly repetitive fields (names and postcodes), and (as the data is large & dynamic) avoiding LOH fragmentation are the key things to consider.

Comment: @Haney Great answer from a hardware perspective, I've been looking for some confirmation on this.